# Custom folder under vendor not loaded on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I bought a theme and want to apply the whole theme into my site.

I put the line in the scss file

*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/css

but it didn't include the folder I want

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> ["pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/app/assets/ace-admin-theme",
 "pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/app/assets/images",
 "pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/app/assets/javascripts",
 "pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/app/assets/lenord-single-page-theme",
 "pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "pixnet_hackathon/website/dqa_streesful_server/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/simple-navigation-bootstrap-1.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bourbon-3.1.8/app/assets/stylesheets",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.0.19/app/assets/javascripts",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.0.19/app/assets/source",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/fonts",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts"]
```

Comment: if u have own coding, just create one new file in vendor/assets/css/ your_file.css . Include the file in application.css in app/assets/css. or you may copy the code and paste it in your css file.

Comment: @Antony whole folder , not just a file.

Comment: U may add the folder in css folder. vendor/assets/css/your_folder. And then include each file from the folder in application.css . for eg: *= require/folder_name/file_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer it using:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/css/.
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Does `*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/css.` this also work?